# Multiband TIFF or .vrt to 1 band tif summing up all bands values

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, geotiff-tiff

I've got 150 monoband raster files (with 0 and 1 values ) and I want to "fuse" or stack them as I would do it with the raster calculator : 
A+B+C.....

I can manage to create a VRT file containing 150 bands but how would I transform it to a monoband TIFF with values going from 0 to 150 ?

Comment: One option is to use gdal_calc python script https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_calc.html but it is written to use input bands A-Z so that it can't take 150 inputs. I guess it is possible to edit the script to accept more inputs.

Comment: Yep ,indeed . a solution for me might be to use it for each .tif creation (rather than waiting having my 150 tiles calculated). But is it possible to flatten each band of a .vrt into one by summing all ?

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS, my suggestion is to use SAGA **Rasters sum** tool (which is in the `Processing Toolbox > SAGA > Raster Calculus`.

Processing 150 raster files would require intensive computing;

- Put your raster files in a folder / directory.
- Restart QGIS first (or at least avoid displaying your raster layers on QGIS canvas).
- Start **Rasters sum** tool.
- Click on the <kbd>...</kbd> button of Grids selection, then click on <kbd>Add Directory...</kbd> and select the folder.

[image]

I have not done this with 150 files... you may have to separate them into several folders and repeat the process.

Comment: Thanks, Indeed I use QGIS ; tested but this takes a very very (too) long time. I wonder if there a way to make it with imagemagick ...